# SQL Server use Full Text Index when using equal expression in where clause instead of contains

Tags: sql-server, database, full-text-search

Can SQL Server use Text Index when supplying the where clause in the format of

```
{select * from TABLE1 where TEXTCOLUMN1='UNIQUETEXTVALUE1'}
```

We have a process flow engine that generates automated queries to retrieve process variable values from SQL Server database. The problem is that variable names are stored in the `NVARCHAR(4000)` column and most of the variable names contain a unique number of the process so they are unique, while only a handful of records out of over a billion rows contains values longer than 1700 bytes. This prevents indexing this column via the normal index as few values are over 1700 bytes limit, but 99.99% of values are less than 128 bytes and unique.

As the engine we are using is built by the third party, we do not have an option to change the way the queries are constructed and they are constructed by Alfresco Content Engine on the fly and frequently contain different joins and columns but regularly refer to the values in this column.

In some cases, other keys are not included, so search takes significant server resources, as it is doing full-table scan, while the query plan shows that optimiser know it is likely to get only 1 hit out of the billion rows, it still performs full scan as there is no suitable index for the constructed query.

We tried truncating the few long values and building the normal index on a table with 512 char length, and that solves the issue completely. However, we cannot put this solution in Production, as occasionally the long value would be populated and the engine will crash.

Can SQL Server use text index for the query

```
select * from TABLE1 where TEXTCOLUMN1='UNIQUETEXTVALUE1'
```

in the same way, it would do then running this query

```
select * from TABLE1 where contains(TEXTCOLUMN1,'UNIQUETEXTVALUE1')
```

It would be good if SQL Server will opt to use available text index if it is available for queries with `where TEXTCOLUMN1='UNIQUETEXTVALUE1'` in the same way it does it with `CONTAINS` function. Can this behaviour be achieved somehow on SQL Server?

Comment: Off-topic for SO - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). But rather than wait to be fed an answer, try it yourself and examine the execution plan.

Comment: As per the execution plan, I can confirm that MS SQL Server does not use text index for equal sign operator. Hence, my question is if this can be configured or not.

Answer (score -1):

I am struggling with this as well. Right now i am thinking of doing a hash of the values in a separate column. Then add an index on the hashed column.
Then when doing a contains do a equals of hashed value on the hashed column.

Text after comments (thanks for pointing out):
I have tried this in test code, yes and it works. I have not implemented it and used in production as it requires more coding on the server and migrations. One article that helped me find what to do: http://thinknook.com/rehashing-sql-server-hashing-algorithms-for-large-text-fields-2013-03-23/

This is a test that i did for a table that contains logging information with nvarchar(max) column that has a full text index.

```
ALTER TABLE XLog ADD HashedMessage AS HashBytes('SHA1', Message) PERSISTED 
    declare @long_text as nvarchar(max);
 set @long_text = 'Failed to schedule something something: Default somethign Clone. The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset'

  select * from XLog WHERE HashedMessage = HASHBYTES('SHA1', @long_text)
```

Beware that if the text variable and column that you have hashed are not the same type this does not work.

Comment: Is this an answer, or a comment? If it is an answer, please read [answer] and [edit] the post for clarity. If this is a comment, please delete this and post it as a comment.

Comment: "i am thinking of doing ..." as in "I never did, did not try, did not research, do not know whether it helps or even works at all". Please delete this and contribute your insights when you actually did successfully. There is such a concept like "parital answer" on StackOverflow, but the agreement is that it should contribute something helpful and solve at least part of the problem.